# "Could not find com.google.jimfs:jimfs:1.1" upgrading RN project to AndroidX

Tags: react-native, android-x86

So i'm going through the joyous task of upgrading to AndroidX in an existing React Native project.  Thus far I've set useAndroidX=true, enableJetifier=true, set the target SdkVersion to 28, and even switched jcenter() above goggle() in the repositories {}.  I keep getting the error "Could not find com.google.jimfs:jimfs:1.1" - and it's friend "Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.21" - help, please!

Comment: so switching jcenter() below mavenCentral() and google() in the repositories section of the build.gradle resolved this issue:
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
    jcenter()
}

Answer (score 32):

Add `mavenCentral()` to project level `build.gradle` file's `repositories` section of `buildscript` and `allprojects`.